# Currency Pipe not found error inside the ionic 5 component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, angular-pipe

I'm using a currency pipe inside my page module without any issues. However, it shows a 'not found error' when using it inside a modal component.

example usage:

```
{{50| currency: 'INR'}}
```

Error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The pipe 'currency' could not be found!
Error: The pipe 'currency' could not be found!
at getPipeDef$1 (core.js:36858)
at ɵɵpipe (core.js:36816)
at SearchComponent_Template (template.html:30)
at executeTemplate (core.js:12156)
```

Environment:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16         
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0
```

The same code is working in the page but fails in the component. Any lights into this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modals are components, not pages. make a `[modal-name].module.ts` file in your modal directory using:

```
ionic g module [modal-name]
```

and import your pipe there.

then you can import it in .ts file and use it with no error. Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Your solution worked fine for me.